# Parent Protocol Delegate method not being called from child didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios5, protocols

I have only been developing for iOS for a couple of months and have been using protocols on a numerous occasions however I have been stuck on this problem for a couple of days.

Here is my code

Child Header File: QuoteSelections.h

```
@protocol myDelegate
 @optional -(void)selectedValueIs:(NSString *)value;   
@end

@interface QuoteSelections : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *ArrDetails;

@property (assign) id<myDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Child Method File: QuoteSelections.m

```
@implementation QuoteSelections
@synthesize delegate;

(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *valueString = @"Test";

    [self.delegate selectedValueIs:valueString];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }
```

I have called the delegate method `selectedValueIs` with a test string.

Here is Parent Header file: newQuoteSec.h

```
@interface newQuoteSec : UITableViewController <myDelegate>  {
    QuoteSelections *quoteSelections;  }
```

Here is my parent Method file: newQuoteSec.m

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    quoteSelections = [[QuoteSelections alloc]init];
    quoteSelections.delegate = self; }

(void)selectedValueIs:(NSString *)value {
    ddlPurposeOfLoan.text = value; }
```

I have set the delegate of the child controller in the `viewDidLoad`,  I thought this should be enough to call my `selectedValueIs` method but it is not.  Why?

---

Here is the edited version recommended by Yogesh

The aim is set the value of the selected item in the second view controller to populate a textfield in the first view controller

QuoteSelections.h

```
@protocol myDelegate

    @optional -(void)selectedValueIs:(NSString *)value;

@end


@interface QuoteSelections : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{

}


@property (assign) id<myDelegate> myDelegate;
```

QuoteSelections.m

```
#import "QuoteSelections.h"

@interface QuoteSelections ()

@end

@implementation QuoteSelections

@synthesize myDelegate;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *valueString = @"Test";

    [self.myDelegate selectedValueIs:valueString];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

newQuoteSec.h

```
@interface newQuoteSec : UITableViewController <STComboTextDelegate, STDateTextDelegate, JSONRPCServiceDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, myDelegate>
{
    QuoteSelections *quoteSelections;
}
```

newQuoteSec.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    quoteSelections = [[QuoteSelections alloc]init];
    quoteSelections.myDelegate = self;
}

-(void)selectedValueIs:(NSString *)value
{
    ddlPurposeOfLoan.text = value;
}
```

Edit...

I have inserted a NSLog just before the delegate is set

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *valueString = @"Test";

    NSLog(@"Showing the delegate didSelectRowAtIndexPath%@", self.myDelegate);

    selectedValue = valueString;

    [self.myDelegate selectedValueIs:valueString];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The output windows shows null

2012-11-27 10:23:59.562 miLoan[18225:c07] Showing the delegate didSelectRowAtIndexPath(null)

Any ideas why? everything else looks good.

I am using storyboards too!

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of delegate in your QuoteSelections Controller class because it already has one delegate (UITableViewDelegate) property.

change

```
@property (assign) id<myDelegate> delegate;
```

to

```
@property (assign) id<myDelegate> myDelegate;
```

and also change at all other places.

Comment: Hi thank you for you reply, i have changed that it has not made a difference, i am thinking if it is in th didSelectRowAtIndexPath method i am missing something

Comment: @Shy9010 is your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method getting called?

Comment: yes its getting called, i checked for self.delegate != nil, but it set to nil,

Comment: is your ViewDidLoad method correct.. it should contain `quoteSelections.myDelegate = self;`

Comment: Yes my viewDidLoad does contain quoteSelections.myDelegate = self as shown above, i just do not understandstand why the method is not being called in the parent.

Comment: Please update the question with new code, that way I would know in case of any mistakes.. and please share anything else that might have caused the problem